# Django symmetrical tabularinline m2m

Tags: python, django, forms

Just starting in Python/Django framework so sorry if this is dumb... but i cant find any solution.

```
model.py
class Apk(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, verbose_name='XXXX')

class ListProductConnections(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Apk, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    related_products = models.ManyToManyField(Apk, related_name='related_product', verbose_name='Є компонентом',)
```

My admin.py

```
class ListProductConnectionsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ListProductConnections
    filter_horizontal = ('related_products',)
    extra = 0 
    max_num = 1  
    verbose_name = 'XXX'
    verbose_name_plural = 'XXX'

class ListProductConnectionsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ListProductConnections
        fields = '__all__'

    related_products = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Apk.objects.all(),
        widget=FilteredSelectMultiple('YYY', is_stacked=False),
        required=False,
    )
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs ):

            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            current_product_id = ListProductConnectionsReversInline.global_variable
            if current_product_id is not None:
                related_products_data = ListProductConnections.related_products.through.objects.filter(
                    apk_id=current_product_id
                ).values_list('listproductconnections_id', flat=True)

                related_products_data_new = ListProductConnections.objects.filter(id__in=related_products_data).values_list('product_id', flat=True)

                initial_product_ids = list(related_products_data_new)

                self.initial['related_products'] = initial_product_ids


class ListProductConnectionsReversInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ListProductConnections
    form = ListProductConnectionsForm
    extra = 0
    max_num = 1
    verbose_name = 'YYY'
    verbose_name_plural = 'YYY'
    global_variable = None

    def get_formset(self, request, obj, **kwargs):
       formset = super(ListProductConnectionsReversInline, self).get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)
       try:
           self.__class__.global_variable = obj.id
       except:
           pass
       return formset


@admin.register(Apk)
class ApkAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    form = FactoryForm
    ....
    inlines = [ListProductConnectionsInline, ListProductConnectionsReversInline]
```

I have a Product, and I want to do the following:

In the ListProductConnectionsInline, select which Products use the Product we are currently editing. This is working perfectly now.

In the ListProductConnectionsReversInline, select which Products are components of the current Product. For example, when editing the Flour Product in ListProductConnectionsInline, we select Bread, and in ListProductConnectionsReversInline, we select Grain. Then, when we go to edit Grain, we can see that it is a component of Flour.

Almost everything is working, but there's one annoying problem. If we have opened a Product in which a Product is already selected in ListProductConnectionsInline, then the widget for ListProductConnectionsReversInline will be open, even if nothing is selected in it.

If nothing is selected in ListProductConnectionsInline, the widget in ListProductConnectionsReversInline will be closed, even if there is a selected item in ListProductConnectionsReversInline. How can I solve this issue and make the widgets open only when something is selected in them?

Sorry for my English